# Cron Job executes multiple times till the entire minute is completed,

Tags: javascript, cron, node-cron

I use the node-cron npm package to run a job that should execute only **ONCE**  every 5 minutes
However , the output i get is that the job executes continously till the entire minute is complete,it executes more than once.

```
cron.schedule('*/5 * * * *', () => {
           console.log('running a task once every 5th minute');
         });
```

Output:

```
running a task once every 5th minute
running a task once every 5th minute
running a task once every 5th minute
running a task once every 5th minute
```

Answer (score 0):

. Execute a cron job every 5 Minutes
The first field is for Minutes. If you specify * in this field, it runs every minutes. If you specify */5 in the 1st field, it runs every 5 minutes as shown below.

```
*/5 * * * * /home/User/backup.sh
```

Note: In the same way, use */10 for every 10 minutes, */15 for every 15 minutes, */30 for every 30 minutes, etc.

2. Execute a cron job every 5 Hours
   The second field is for hours. If you specify * in this field, it runs every hour. If you specify */5 in the 2nd field, it runs every 5 hours as shown below.

   ```
   0 */5 * * * /home/User/backup.sh
   ```

It will surely run for 5 hours only.

Rewrite it and then run.